# Cannot mock Android drawable using @Mockk annotation?

Tags: android, mockk

I want to mock an Android drawable for some unit tests. I'm using the `@Mockk` annotations. This is the code:

```
@MockK
lateinit var mockIcon: Drawable

@Before
fun setUp() {
    MockKAnnotations.init(this)
}
```

When I run this code, I get this error `lateinit property mockIcon has not been initialized`

But when I use the `mockk()` function instead, the code runs successfully:

```
val mockIcon: Drawable = mockk()
```

I don't understand what causes this issue. Is there a difference between the `@Mockk` annotation and `mockk()` function?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Generally don't want to mock android classes. Junit is java and doesnt know about the android stack.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. I just need to use the mock as a placeholder for some dependency in a model class. Something like: `val tModel = MyModel(icon = mockIcon,...)`

Comment: Can you show more codes? I made a simple test and it passed. My code : https://pastebin.com/xLzKAYgQ